# filter simplexml result

Tags: php, simplexml

how to filter the result to show only torrent with keyword "848"
my code

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.animesuki.com/xml.php?type=groups&id=1157";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("Could not load file!"); 
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">';
echo "<channel>";
$i = 0;
foreach ($xml->release as $getrelease => $value)
{
    if (++$i > 10) {
        break;
    }
   echo "<item>";
   echo  "<title>".$getrelease->filename."</title>";
   echo "<link>".$getrelease->torrent[0]->direct."</link>";
   echo "</item>";
}
echo "</channel>";
?>
```

thank

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this.

1) if for example the filename should *only* contain the keyword 848; you should do this:

```
<?php if($getrelease->filename == '848') { ?>
```

2) if you also want to match foobar848 and bla848blabla, you should use a regular expression:

```
<?php if(preg_match('/848/', $getrelease->filename)) { ?>
```

But I guess this is very basic PHP stuff, if you don't understand the concept of an if-loop, maybe you should read some books first :).